# Web service putting Soap message in queue with Spring Integration and Jms

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-jms

I want to use Spring Integration to expose a simple web service that pushes incoming message into ActiveMQ and responds immediately. My go-to solution was MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway connected to Jms.outboundAdapter with IntegrationFlow. Below the Gateway and IntegrationFlow snippets. Problem with this is Adapter does not provide response (duh) which Gateway expects. The response I get back from the service is empty 202, with delay of about 1500ms. This is caused by a reply timeout I see in TRACE logs:

```
"2020-04-14 17:17:50.101 TRACE 26524 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.integration.core.MessagingTemplate   : Failed to receive message from channel 'org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@518ffd27' within timeout: 1000"
```

No hard exceptions anywhere. The other problem is I cannot generate the response myself. I can't add anything to IntegrationFlow after the .handle with Adapter.

1. Any other way I can try to fulfill the scenario?
2. How, if at all possible, can I generate and return response in situation there is no better approach?

Most likely the proper way would be to use Gateways on both ends, but this is not possible. I cannot wait with response until message in the queue gets consumed and processed.

'''

```
@Bean
public MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway greetingWebServiceInboundGateway() {
    MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway inboundGateway = new MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway(
            jaxb2Marshaller()
    );
    inboundGateway.setRequestChannelName("greetingAsync.input");
    inboundGateway.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    return inboundGateway;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow greetingAsync() {
    return f -> f
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)
            .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
                    .configureJmsTemplate(c -> {
                        c.jmsMessageConverter(new MarshallingMessageConverter(jaxb2Marshaller()));
                    })
                    .destination(JmsConfig.HELLO_WORLD_QUEUE));

}
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic and assumptions are fully correct: you can't return after one-way `handle()` and similar to that `Jms.outboundAdapter()`.

But your problem that you fully miss one of the first-class citizens in Spring Integration - a `MessageChannel`. It is important to understand that even in the flow like yours there are channels between endpoints (DSL methods) - implicit (`DirectChannel`), like in your case, or explicit: when you use a `channel()` in between and can place there any possible implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-channels

One of the crucial channel implementation is a `PublishSubscribeChannel` (a `topic` in JMS specification) when you can send the same message to several subscribed endpoints: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel

In your case the fists subscriber should be your existing, one-way `Jms.outboundAdapter()`. And another something what is going to generate response and reply it into a `replyChannel` header.

For this purpose Java DSL provides a nice hook via sub-flows configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows

So, some sample of publish-subscriber could be like this:

```
.publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c
                        .subscribe(sf -> sf
                                  .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(this.jmsConnectionFactory))))
.handle([PRODUCE_RESPONSE])
```

Comment: You are a godsend! I have one question, though. If I understand this correctly, the moment you split the flow, you can get into ugly situation where you can fail to put something on queue, but respond with success. How do you avoid that?

Comment: That's not always correct. See `ignoreFailures` option which is `false` by default. As long as  you don't provide any `Executor` to the `PublishSubscribeChannel` the first subscriber is going to block a thread until it finishes its work or fails. So, the second subscriber won't perform its job until the first has finished and only when successfully. See the docs about `PublishSubscribeChannel` I've pointed in the answer.